# Encountered な with ten-ten

Tags: grammar, pronunciation, orthography, hiragana

I am currently reading a manga for studying Japanese and encountered something strange. A girl exclaims「な゛?!」

The situation is that she has just had water squirted up her nose, so I am guessing it's a kind of 'gnya' sound?

So my question is, is this a real Japanese language thing, or is it just the artist taking liberties with the language for comic effect?

Cheers

Comment: perhaps you could attach a small picture?

Comment: You might want to check out this old (2002) thread about this sort of thing: http://q.hatena.ne.jp/1040004428#a7692  Interesting thread :)

Comment: @Flaw Just to be careful, are there any guidelines about "[fair use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use)" (for anything copyright-related) on SE?

Comment: @summea I don't know about that. But I really doubt part of an image of a comic frame will affect their profits. I guess it's fair use for educational purposes. We can remove the image on request anyway.

Comment: i think it just means the voice is strained.

Comment: Related question: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15270/why-are-points-used-where-furigana-would-be-normally

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We sometimes write 「な!?」,「なっ!?」 or 「なっ・・・!?」 (These three will be pronounced the same way) to mean 「なにっ！？」 or 「何！？」.  Probably it's like "Wha...!?" or "What the...!?"

We also sometimes write 「え゛っ！」 in place of 「えっ！」 to add emphasis, but the 「゛」 ([濁点]{だくてん}) won't change/affect the pronunciation, so it'd be impossible to pronounce 「な゛」 or 「え゛」 correctly (I don't know what would be "correct" here though).

However, if I were a voice actress and had to read them, I'd probably read them as...

[「え゛っ！」](http://vocaroo.com/i/s0YZv2DMG8AA)
instead of 
[「えっ！」](http://vocaroo.com/i/s1OamI04IXob)

(So... maybe you'd call it a "thick/gruff/husky(?) voice"?? Or, is this what you'd call "strained", as in @ogicu8abruok's comment?)

Comment: ナ行の音は鼻音で既に有声です。つまり、声帯の振動を伴った音なので、濁点をつけても更に濁らせたりする事は不可能です。

Comment: So writing え゛っ(with the extra ゛) as opposed to  えっ denotes added surprise without denoting an actual change in sound? (by the way what are those dots called in Japanese and in English?)

Comment: @yadokari Besides 濁点（だくてん）, they are sometimes called 濁り（にごり） or colloquially てんてん.  In English, you can use Japanese terms like "dakuten" or call them "voicing marks" or "voiced sound marks".

Comment: @Dono そ～ですよねえ。。。もうちょっと考えて書き直そう・・・（しかもまた日本語やし）

Comment: なるほど、よく分かった。ありがとう

Comment: @DaleyPaley え゛っ・・・そうですか？(゜o゜)゛　自分では良いと思わなかったので、ずいぶん書き直してしまいました。う゛む゛む゛・・・

Answer (score 3):

I believe in this instance, the dots are used for emphasis. Since な is only a sound (or partial word), the net effect is basically just a louder exclamation. It's the difference between writing "What!?" and "*What*!?" in English (note the italics).