# Encountered や with tenten

Tags: pronunciation

I started reading something my friend got for me from Japan and came across や with tenten and am not quite sure how to pronounce it. I've never come across it before and I've been trying to find a possible answer anywhere online but haven't had any luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add more context? Maybe even a clear picture would work.

Comment: Could it be possible to describe  "や with tenten"? Does tenten you correspond "てんてん” in Japanese?

Comment: Probably 「や゛っ！」?

Comment: 「や゛」<-- Something like this? Would this thread be of any help? --> https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11898/9831

Comment: I think it's the same thing as that other thread - a 濁点 added for effect/emphasis with no real grammatical meaning.